# How to launch application and bring it to front using Cocoa api?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm very new to a cocoa programming and I can't find the way to do the following:

- Start a particular application by name
- Do some work
- Later bring that application I've started to be the front process

From what I've found in Carbon API it looks like the calls i should use are launchApplication() and setFrontProcess().

But how to do this in Cocoa? I.e. launch it, get PID, set that PID to be a front process. I tried to google for examples and find nothing...

If any of you can provide a minimalistic sample that would be awesome :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To launch an application :

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"/Applications/Safari.app"];
```

To activate an app :

```
NSRunningApplication* app = [NSRunningApplication
                             runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: PID];
[app activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
// or
NSArray* apps = [NSRunningApplication
                 runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.bla.blah"];
[(NSRunningApplication*)[apps objectAtIndex:0]
 activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
```

Comment: I tried to launch an app this way from a background process, but it seems that this method of launching doesn't work in Lion or later if the process doing it is not a GUI application.

Comment: The `NSApplicationActivateAllWindows` option will cause all of the Application window to come forward, which is almost always not what you want. Instead you can pass in `NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps` to just activate the window that was most recently active in the app.

Answer (score 4):

To start an application, use the `NSWorkspace` class: [NSWorkspace Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Specifically, the `launchApplication:` function.

I don't know the answer of the activation part off my head. You can activate your own application with `-[NSApplication activateIgnoringOtherApps:]`, but I don't know how to do it for other apps.

Comment: Thanks. That's the right function, yes, I saw it, but i can't find a way to find pid and reuse it later. Let's wait maybe someone knows the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into [NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 1):

NSRunningApplication is available on Mac OS X 10.6 or later.

If you have to support earlier systems, this can be done with APIs such as GetCurrentProcess() and SetFrontProcess() and the old ProcessSerialNumber structure.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift2 version

Launch App:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments = ["/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"]
task.launch()
```

To get the app using bundle Identifier:

```
    var apps: [AnyObject] = NSRunningApplication.runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.TextEdit")
    var MyApp: [NSRunningApplication] = apps as! [NSRunningApplication]        
            for app in MyApp        
            {
            }
```

I am still trying to find the way to know "active", "hide" etc state of app, But not succeed till now.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4, you can use `NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(appName:)` to open an app. It also makes the launched app at front in my case.

You also can try:

```
do {
    try NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(at: yourAppURL,
                                             options: .andHideOthers,
                                             configuration: [:])
} catch {
    printError("Failed to launch the app.")
}
```

> Option `andHideOthers`: Hide all apps except the newly launched one.

Answer (score 0):

Open App in Mac in Objective C

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"/Applications/Books.app"];
    }
    return 0;
}
```