# Comparing different 'the launching Cocoa app with parameters' methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I found there are at least three ways to launch an app with Mac OS X from an application.

1. [NSTask](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTaskArguments). I can give parameters, but it seems that it's not for an Cocoa App, but an UNIX style binary.
2. system function (system()) just the same way as C does. I don't know the reason why but it seems that nobody recommends this method.
3. [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but I can't find a way to pass parameters to this function.

#### Questions

- Q1 : Is there any other way to launch an App (from an App) other than three methods?
- Q2 : What's the pros and cons for each method?
- Q3 : What's the preferable way for launching an App (from an App)?
- Q4 : What's the preferable way for launching an App with parameters (from an App)?
- Q5 : What's the preferable way to open a document (from an App)?

### ADDED

- `NSWorkspace openFile:withApplication:` : For running "TextMate README.txt", based on [Roadmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330067/launching-app-with-parameters-using-launchedtaskwithlaunchpath-objecive-c-functio) and [this code](http://theocacao.com/document.page/194/), I could make it as follows.
  But, **I can't give the parameters to the App.**

```
    NSString * path = @"/Users/smcho/Desktop/README.txt";
    NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
    NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
    [ws openFile:[fileURL path] withApplication:@"TextMate"];
```

- `NSWorkspace launchApplicationAtURL:options:` : **It works with 10.6 or later**, you can get an example from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332049/how-to-use-nsworkspace-launchapplicationaturl).

```
    NSURL * bURL = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.macromates.textmate"];
    NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
    [ws launchApplicationAtURL:bURL options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault configuration:nil error:nil];
```

- `NSTask` : This is the working code. I need to give the correct binary path, and **it doesn't look like a Cocoa way, as it's for running binary, not bundle.** Though, it's possible to give more parameters than just a file name.

```
    [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/MacOS/TextMate"     arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello.txt", nil]];
```

- `system()` : With the shell, I could run "system(open -a ABC --args hello.txt)", just like I do with the command line. **It seems that this is the easiest way to go.**

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to launch it? On startup? When the user clicks a button? And one of the reasons `system` isn't recommended is that it requires a shell. This could be a problem if the user were to run the app in a chroot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 10.6 and later, NSWorkspace has a method `launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:` that can be used to pass arguments to the app.

There are also Launch Services functions such as `LSOpenItemsWithRole`.

You could also send an AppleEvent to the Finder asking it to open something.

EDIT TO ADD: "best" is subjective, but I'd say if you can use NSWorkspace, use it.  If you can't, e.g., you need to pass command-line parameters and you need to support Leopard, then use Launch Services.

Answer (score 0):

By using Scripting Bridge, you can use the method `activate` to launch a cocoa app. See: [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html).