# LaunchApplication with command line arguments

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to call another app from my app, and send it some command line arguments. Using launchApplication works well, but I don;t know how to send the command line arguments with it.
System() will send command line args, but the app appears behind the calling app.

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331401/comparing-different-the-launching-cocoa-app-with-parameters-methods) for some hints.

Under Snow Leopard, you can use [`launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:)

to pass arguments. Simply build a configuration dictionary giving `NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments` as key to your array of arguments.

Comment: It looks like you meant to include a link to another question, but didn't.

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Unfortunately the app appears beneath the one that called it. Is there a way to programmatically bring it to the front?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333078/how-to-launch-application-and-bring-it-to-front-using-cocoa-api

Comment: It still stays behind using that solution, although I had to change PID to  pID to get it to compile:                 NSRunningApplication* myApp=[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: pID];
    [myApp activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];

Comment: forgive me, but having to change PID to pID does not make any sense to me... just for clarity: PID (or whatever its name) should be the process id of the process you just started with `launchApplicationAtURL`; or just use the other syntax (bundle identifier)... if you don't have the PID (which I suspect), use the other syntax and specify the bundle identifier...

Comment: Sorry. I'm new at Cocoa. I tried the other method, [(NSRunningApplication*)[apps objectAtIndex:0] activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows]; and I think I'm getting a good apps pointer (it's not null...), but it crashes when that line is run.

Comment: what error do you get (cmd-shift-r to display the console log) and what is the stack trace?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5316/discussion-between-bill-ferster-and-sergio)