# Can Xcode open an application without fork?

Tags: xcode, macos

My question is just that. Is there a command in Xcode that uses a process other than fork?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333078/how-to-launch-application-and-bring-it-to-front-using-cocoa-api

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app

Comment: @middaparka why did you break the spelling of Xcode in edits?

Comment: @Richard - My bad. I thought that "XCode" was the official spelling, but am clearly epically wrong. (Bit late in the day, clearly time to step away from the keyboard.) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other APIs to launch applications, but they all ultimately rely on `fork()/exec()`. There's no other way on UNIX to start a new process from userland than forking an existing process. You can install another task as a `launchd` job, then launch it by satisfying its start conditions - that doesn't directly use `fork()` (though of course it causes `launchd` to fork).